# Elementos mudando de posição quando a tela é redimensionada

Tags: html, css

Boa tarde, estou aprendendo position e queria saber qual o erro nesse código, pois as imagens ficam na posição que eu quero quando a a tela está cheia, mas quando a tela é redimensionada eles mudam um pouco a posição, alguém pode me ajudar pra que eles fiquem na mesma posição independente do tamanho da tela?

Meu código:

```css
@keyframes pular{
    0%, 20%, 60%, 100%{
        -webkit-transfomr: translateY(0);
        transform: translateY(0)
    }
    40%{
        -webkit-transfomr: translateY(-20px);
        transform: translateY(-20px)
    }
    80%{
        -webkit-transfomr: translateY(-10px);
        transform: translateY(-10px)
    }
}

.pulo:hover{
    animation: pular 1s;
}

/*///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////*/

.margem-esquerda{
    margin-left: -20%;
}

.video{
    max-width:100%;
    height:auto;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;  
    position:relative;
}

#imagem-position{
    position:absolute;
    top:0%;
    right:0%;
    margin-top:47%;
    margin-right: 36%;
    max-width: 30%;
    max-height: 59%;
    padding-top: 10%;
    margin-left: 10%;
}

/*#imagem-position2{
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 0%;
    right: 0%;
    margin-right: 25%;
}
*/


.transicao{
    max-width:100%;
    height:auto;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;  
    margin-top: -10%;
    
    
}

.circulo{
    max-width:100%;
    height:auto;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0; 
    position:relative;
    top:0%;
    margin-top: -105%;

}

.pedra{
    max-width:48%;
    height:auto;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0; 
    position:absolute;
    top:0%;
    margin-top:55.5%;
    margin-right: 26%;
    margin-left:-10%;
}

#sombra{
    max-width:100%;
    height:auto;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0; 
    top:0%;
    position:relative;
    margin-top: -1%;
    margin-left:0%;

}



/*/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Pokemon Generations</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="Logo/Dream_Poké_Ball_Sprite.png">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width, initial scale=1.0">
        <meta name="author" content="Daniel Lucas">
        <meta name="description" content="Tela Inicial do site">
        <meta name="keywords" content="pokémon,bingo,história">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/compiler/bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/compiler/style.css">
        <script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.js"></script>
        <script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

    <body style="background-image:url(Fundo/fundo_triangulo_roxo.png)">
        <nav class="navbar sticky-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark" style="background-color:#38102b; overflow:auto;" > 
            <div class="container fixado">
                
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSite">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span> 
                </button>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="navbarSite" > 
                    <ul class="navbar-nav">
                       <img>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link mt-2" class="margem-esquerda"href="#"><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning" class="ml-1"><img src="Icones/icone_personagens_gold.png" >Personagens</button></a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link  mt-2" class="margem-esquerda"href="#"><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning" class="ml-1"><img src="Icones/icone_comojogar_gold.png" >Como jogar</button></a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link  mt-2" href="#"><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning" class="ml-1"><img src="Icones/icone_jogar_gold1.png" >Jogar</button></a></li>
                        <a class="navbar-brand h1 mb-0 " href="site_inicial.htm"><img src="Logo/shining_legends.png"></a>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link mt-2" href="#"><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning" class="ml-1"><img src="Icones/icone_atualizacoes_gold.png" >Atualizações</button></a></li>
                        
                        <li class="nav-item "><a class="nav-link mt-2" href="#"><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning" class="ml-1"><img src="Icones/icone_quemsou_gold.png" >Quem Sou</button></a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item " id="charmander"><a class="navbar-brand h1 mb-0 pulo mt-2" target="_blank" href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC6VdsMMnL-GdcoKc9qZEtQA?disable_polymer=true"><img src="Icones/icone_charmander.png"></a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="navbar-brand h1 mb-0 pulo mt-2" target="_blank " href="http://api.whatsapp.com/send?1=pt_BR&phone=5584996011922"><img src="Icones/icone_bulbasaur.png"></a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="navbar-brand h1 mb-0 pulo mt-2" target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/LegendsShining"><img src="Icones/icone_squirtle.png"></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                
            </div>
        </nav>

        
        <div>
            <video  class="video" autoplay loop muted="true" >  
                <source src="Fundo/fundo_prisma_full.mp4" type="video/mp4" >
            </video>
            <img src="Fundo/fundo_preto_best_oficial_real_oficial.png" id="sombra">
            <img src="Fundo/fundo_circulo_cinza.png" class="circulo">
            <img src="Fundo/fundo_placa_pedra_dourado_novo.png" class="pedra">
            <img src="Fundo/1200px-Shining_Legends_Logo.png" id="imagem-position">
        </div>
        
        <div style="width:100%;height:600px;margin-top:-1%; margin-bottom:20%; background-color:black;"> 
        </div>
       

        
        

    

    </body>
</html>
```

foto da tela full: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Foto da tela redimensionada: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

OBS: Se alguém quiser o arquivo do programa com as imagens e vídeos eu mando pelo email

Comment: Cara suas medidas de margin e padding estão todas em %, então com valores em porcentagem é comum em telas com tamanhos diferentes os elementos mudarem de posição... Tente usar valores em pixels para essas coisas que vai facilitar pra vc

Comment: Mas fica redimensionado? Pq assim, meu prof meio que incentivou a gente a usar % por causa do redimensionamento e talz.

Comment: Evite medidas em % principalmente no padding, pq o padding em % é relativo a largura do container, não funciona exatamente como vc imagina... tente deixar as% para width, height e margin em alguns casos, mas não para padding. Outra coisa, vc não deixou claro como quer que a imagem fique em telas pequenas. Nomo a imagem deve ficar quando em telas menores??

Comment: Eu queria que elas ficassem exatamente como ficam em tela cheia, ou então o mais próximo disso.